Как добавить в Inno setup дополнительное ПО
вот скрипт
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{3ECA1D37-945B-4D05-B21E-5EE5508474A9}
AppName=SpiderTV
AppVersion=0.1
;AppVerName=SpiderTV 0.1
AppPublisher=Nikula Company, Inc.
DefaultDirName={autopf}\SpiderTV
ChangesAssociations=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\nikul\OneDrive\Desktop\License.txt
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\nikul\OneDrive\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\nikul\Downloads\19_icon-icons.com_73796.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "D:\source\repos\SpiderTV\SpiderTV\bin\x64\Release\SpiderTV.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\source\repos\SpiderTV\SpiderTV\bin\x64\Release\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.myp\OpenWithProgids"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SpiderTVFile.myp"; ValueData: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\SpiderTVFile.myp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "SpiderTV File"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\SpiderTVFile.myp\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\SpiderTV.exe,0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\SpiderTVFile.myp\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\SpiderTV.exe"" ""%1"""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\SpiderTV.exe\SupportedTypes"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".myp"; ValueData: ""

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\SpiderTV"; Filename: "{app}\SpiderTV.exe"
Name: "{autodesktop}\SpiderTV"; Filename: "{app}\SpiderTV.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\SpiderTV.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,SpiderTV}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

`
как мне сделать так что бы после установки основной программы установил NDP481-DevPack-ENU.exe?
